# How to put the results of an eval() into an object

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

I have a string that contains a few unspecified functions. 
Is there a way to eval() this string and store the resulting functions that are compiled into an Object or Array?

Desired output after doing eval(string):

```
{ a: f() , 
  b: f() , 
  c: f() }
```

If I then do this with another string, which may also coincidentally contain functions of the same name, I don't want it to overwrite the first ones:

```
funcs[0] = eval(string1)
funcs[1] = eval(string2) 

funcs looks like: 
[{ a: f(), b: f() }, 
 { a: f(), c: f() }]
```

where the two a's here are actually different functions.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. There's almost certainly a much more elegant method - don't use `eval`

Comment: I'm very open to hearing an alternative for compiling functions from strings that aren't received until after page load. I asked a question on that yesterday here, where the only suggestion was to use eval: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850397/how-to-send-additional-javascript-code-to-client-from-nodejs-server-after-page-l

Comment: Also since function will be a Pinter,I think it should now have any issues with collision according to JavaScript. I agree though with above iuser. I would though slit each out,then push onto array or property etc. the Robles though if containing some names to identify but different functions pointers, why would you want that? I would split and index like f1,f2and so on disregarding naming. If thatmak s sense.

Comment: Figure out how you can represent the different ways the popup can be rendered in an object, have the server send an object like that, and parse it in the client-side Javascript, without any `eval`.